# failed to connect after testing smtp connection

Tags: email, smtp

I am testing smtp connection with my website using mxtoolbox and i get as result this error could you please explain what does it mean , is it a problem need to be fixed , could affect somehow my deliverability ?

Connecting to 104.237.59.195
10/8/2015 5:51:26 AM Connection attempt #1 - Unable to connect after 15 seconds. [15.00 sec]

PWS3v2 15176ms